# Java RandomAccessFile Deleting Original text

Tags: java, file-io, randomaccessfile

So i was using RandomAccessFile for reading and writing in java. But when I write a string to the file the current contents of the file are being overridden. Here is my Code

```
    import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
public class hello{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    RandomAccessFile a;
    try{
      a = new RandomAccessFile("a.txt", "rw");
      System.out.println(a.readLine());
      a.writeUTF("another text");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my file content

```
101 yes no  yes no
102 no  no  yes no
103 yes no  yes no
104 no  no  yes no
105 no  yes no  no
106 yes yes yes no
```

but when I run the program it becomes

```
101 yes no  yes no
another text    no
103 yes no  yes no
104 no  no  yes no
105 no  yes no  no
106 yes yes yes no
```

what did I do wrong?

Comment: RandomAcessFile#writeUTF starts writing/overwriting content at the position of the cursor and since you already read one line using `a.readLine()`, your file pointer is positioned at the start of the second line. It's also best practice to close your file stream with `a.close()` after you finished writing/reading.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if this is your issue but I noticed that there is a [seek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek(long)) method on RandomAccessFile that allows you to move the file pointer to the end of the file for writes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the length of the file

```
long fileLength = a.length();
```

Then you need to offset the file pointer to that position, so you can write to it.

```
a.seek(fileLength);
```

That will fix your problem. 
On a side note, you need to close your resources. Maybe try-with-resources:

```
 try (RandomAccessFile a = new RandomAccessFile("a.txt", "rw")) {
            long fileLength = a.length();
            a.seek(fileLength);
            System.out.println(a.readLine());
            a.writeUTF("another text");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Obviously depending on the version of Java you are working with: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: but can't I write in the second line without overwriting the existing line

Comment: @KidUser have you tried my fix. It will write the line "another text" at the end.

Comment: yes I have tried it but the file pointer goes to the end and "another text" is written in the end I want it to be written on the second line